# Create a bootable Windows 7 clone to ssd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

How do I create a bootable Windows 7 clone from my hard drive to my SSD?

Specifically, how can I do that using

Control Panel > Backup and Restore > Create a system image.

It looks like this is creating an image file and not a boot drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning Windows with something like Acronis, Ghost or some freeware (usually Linux based) utility would be way easier.

I believe the system image is a data image which may be able to be used as a VHD but I'm not sure.

Here is a similar post and answer on a Microsoft site.  http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/b1da3bc0-07c2-4c15-b69b-19f6c2e21915

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I DriveImage XML Backup but it would not boot and was full of errors, although I can't say it wasn't user error. I then tried EaseUs and it worked first try!